ECO Repo error on for multi-tenacy environment
Onemedical.Router.pipe_through11/1
10:59:10.760 erl_level=error domain=cowboy pid=<0.25737.8> [error] #PID<0.10695.9> running Onemedical.Endpoint (connection #PID<0.25737.8>, stream id 79) terminated
Server: api.onemedicalfile.com:80 (http)
Request: GET /socket/websocket?token=neerGyGIwvQxzUDqj1xDWuCbDbaHrS20phoju4_OK0Hzopds2y6Sr-2sVVgNfIG-1unczoiSiPgQVbsxvJwIIQ&origin=jerouhospital.onemedicalfile.com&vsn=2.0.0
** (exit) an exception was raised:
** (RuntimeError) could not lookup Ecto repo :client1 because it was not started or it does not exist
(ecto 3.4.6) lib/ecto/repo/registry.ex:19: Ecto.Repo.Registry.lookup/1
(ecto 3.4.6) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:173: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.execute/4
(ecto 3.4.6) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:17: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.all/3
(ecto 3.4.6) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:112: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.one/3
(onemedical 3.14.6-12308-g8b62465d0) lib/onemedical/accounts/sessions.ex:23: Onemedical.Accounts.Sessions.get/1
(onemedical 3.14.6-12308-g8b62465d0) lib/onemedical_web/channels/user_socket.ex:18: Onemedical.UserSocket.connect/2
(phoenix 1.5.14) lib/phoenix/socket.ex:566: Phoenix.Socket.user_connect/4
(phoenix 1.5.14) lib/phoenix/socket.ex:434: Phoenix.Socket.connect/3
10:59:10.780 erl_level=error domain=cowboy pid=<0.24921.8> [error] #PID<0.10692.9> running Onemedical.Endpoint (connection #PID<0.24921.8>, stream id 143) terminated
Server: api.onemedicalfile.com:80 (http)
Request: GET /socket/websocket?token=Vi3kSVyGu4j96Fb_fN_lYyCij5-_L6OD-wMvKvZpRgp8DNKRHx1o6MHGIc452_62ZyNEoMvQxESrPJXuDdXHig&origin=chironhospital.onemedicalfile.com&vsn=2.0.0
** (exit) an exception was raised:
** (RuntimeError) could not lookup Ecto repo :client2 because it was not started or it does not exist
(ecto 3.4.6) lib/ecto/repo/registry.ex:19: Ecto.Repo.Registry.lookup/1
(ecto 3.4.6) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:173: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.execute/4
(ecto 3.4.6) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:17: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.all/3
(ecto 3.4.6) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:112: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.one/3
(onemedical 3.14.6-12308-g8b62465d0) lib/onemedical/accounts/sessions.ex:23: Onemedical.Accounts.Sessions.get/1
(onemedical 3.14.6-12308-g8b62465d0) lib/onemedical_web/channels/user_socket.ex:18: Onemedical.UserSocket.connect/2
(phoenix 1.5.14) lib/phoenix/socket.ex:566: Phoenix.Socket.user_connect/4
(phoenix 1.5.14) lib/phoenix/socket.ex:434: Phoenix.Socket.connect/3
10:59:11.828 erl_level=notice domain=otp file=application_controller.erl function=info_exited/3 line=1943 mfa=:application_controller.info_exited/3 module=application_controller pid=<0.5666.0> [notice] Application onemedical exited: shutdown
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_terminated,onemedical,shutdown}"}
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_terminated,onemedical,shutdown})
Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
ChatGPT
I need solutions on how one can resolve this kind of issue
